# Compiler error in a java program

Tags: java, arrays

this is my first post so here goes,
I am currently writing a bit of a program and i am currently trying to swap two indices in an array and i believe i have it done correct but i am getting a compiler error which i just cant get my head around. If anyone could tell me why im getting the error it would be much appreciated. This is the asking the user for input and error checking and it works fine

```
/////***************** Question 1 Part F (Method inside of Main)  *****************\\\\\    
System.out.print ("\n");
System.out.println ("Press 1 to edit the array: ");
int changeArray = keyIn.nextInt();

if(changeArray==1){
    //Ask to change indice 1
    System.out.println("Please enter the first indice you want to edit: (Between 0 & " + numbers.size() + ")");
    int changeFirstIndice = keyIn.nextInt();

    //Error check the first indice
    if (changeFirstIndice > numbers.size() || changeFirstIndice < 0) {
        System.out.println("ERROR!! You have entered an invalid number, please try again...");
    } //Ask to change indice 2
    else if (changeFirstIndice <= numbers.get(numbers.size() - 1) && changeFirstIndice > 0) {
        System.out.println("Please enter the second indice you want to edit: (Between 0 & " + numbers.size() + ")");
        int changeSecondIndice = keyIn.nextInt();

        //Error check the second indice
        if (changeSecondIndice > numbers.size() || changeSecondIndice < 0) {
            System.out.println("ERROR!! You have entered an invalid number, please try again...");
        } //Print the adjusted array
        else if (changeSecondIndice <= numbers.size() && changeFirstIndice > 0) {
            changeIndices(numbers, changeFirstIndice, changeSecondIndice);
            System.out.println(numbers);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code that is giving me errors and for the life of me cant see whats wrong (it will probably be something simple )

```
public static ArrayList changeIndices(ArrayList<Integer> numbers, int changeFirstIndice, int changeSecondIndice) {
    int temp1 = numbers.get((changeFirstIndice) - 1);
    int temp2 = numbers.get((changeSecondIndice) - 1);

    //Swap the numbers
    numbers.set((changeFirstIndice - 1), temp2);
    numbers.set((changeSecondIndice - 1), temp1);

    return numbers;
}
```

[These are the errors that im getting] http://gyazo.com/4b3ccbb8316242a9335d5fb4b006dec0

So as previously stated any help would be greatly apprecited :)
For the people asking here is all the code involved in this part:

```
/////***************** Question 1 Part F (Method inside of Main)  *****************\\\\\    
System.out.print("\n");
System.out.println("Press 1 to edit the array: ");
int changeArray = keyIn.nextInt();

if (changeArray == 1) {
    //Ask to change indice 1
    System.out.println("Please enter the first indice you want to edit: (Between 0 & " + numbers.size() + ")");
    int changeFirstIndice = keyIn.nextInt();

    //Error check the first indice
    if (changeFirstIndice > numbers.size() || changeFirstIndice < 0) {
        System.out.println("ERROR!! You have entered an invalid number, please try again...");
    }

    //Ask to change indice 2
    else if (changeFirstIndice <= numbers.get(numbers.size() - 1) && changeFirstIndice > 0) {
        System.out.println("Please enter the second indice you want to edit: (Between 0 & " + numbers.size() + ")");
        int changeSecondIndice = keyIn.nextInt();

        //Error check the second indice
        if (changeSecondIndice > numbers.size() || changeSecondIndice < 0) {
            System.out.println("ERROR!! You have entered an invalid number, please try again...");
        }

        //Print the adjusted array
        else if (changeSecondIndice <= numbers.size() && changeFirstIndice > 0) {
            changeIndices(numbers, changeFirstIndice, changeSecondIndice);

            System.out.println(numbers);
        }
    }
}

/////***************** Question 1 Part F (Method Outside of Main)  *****************\\\\\
public static ArrayList changeIndices(ArrayList < Integer > numbers, int changeFirstIndice, int changeSecondIndice) {
    int temp1 = numbers.get((changeFirstIndice) - 1);
    int temp2 = numbers.get((changeSecondIndice) - 1);

    //Swap the numbers
    numbers.set((changeFirstIndice - 1), temp2);
    numbers.set((changeSecondIndice - 1), temp1);

    return numbers;
}
```

So as previously stated any help would be greatly apprecited :)

Comment: [The link](http://gyazo.com/4b3ccbb8316242a9335d5fb4b006dec0) can be broken. Please copy & paste those errors here. It cannot be copied. It is an image.

Comment: Thanks for posting. Can you give us the 4 or so lines directly above changeIndices(?

Comment: Is `changeIndices()` public or private? The compiler output is different. But, the problem is likely the space between the method name and left brace. Try recompiling without that. Edit: just a convention I guess.

Comment: It's really hard to read your first method given the poor indentation. Please fix that - it may well show you where the error is.

Comment: Yes, in the future copy/paste all relevant error messages directly into your question.

Comment: @clwhisk -- What's wrong with having a space there?  Whitespace can appear basically anywhere other than actually within a symbol or keyword.

Comment: This is kind of awkward but at the minute im not exactly amazing at this programming and when you say that the indentation is poor, how would you advise fixing it? (Genuinely curious as this is the way i am being taught to indent) sorry :(

Comment: "Illegal start of expression", pointing directly at the header line of a method, pretty much inevitably means that you're missing a `}` or `)` or `;` somewhere in the preceding lines.

Comment: Again, can you please post the four or so lines *preceding* the error so we can find your mistake? They're really hard to find with the relevant code visible, and even harder without that code.

Comment: Unfortunately, when you paste here you sometimes (depending on multiple factors) lose indentation.  But, generally, each successive `{}` nesting level should be indented 4 spaces.  There is a religious war over whether the `{` following an `if` or `for` or `while` should be on the same line or on the next line (I favor the same line).

Comment: It's likely that your first problem is that the definition of changeIndices falls inside the prior method, rather than after its closing `}`.  (In fact, with the latest update above that definitely appears to be the problem.)  (But likely there are other problems.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that there is no `}` at the end of your code where your `main` method should end, before the declaration of the method `public static ArrayList changeIndices(...`

Using an IDE, or even a programming editor like NotePad++ would help you with brace matching

Comment: I just realised that i was meant to put the method outside of main but wasnt closing the main before that, so Java Devil was right in saying that i forgot to close my main, MANY THANKS GOOD SIR :)

Comment: @user2880298 Thanks for providing relevant info to the question. Many times other users don't realize what's relevant then never notice/act upon comments asking for extra info.

Answer (score -5):

The method arguments need to immediately follow the method name (without the space):

```
public static ArrayList changeIndices(ArrayList <Integer> numbers, int changeFirstIndice, int changeSecondIndice)
```

Comment: That's completely untrue. It's entirely valid to have whitespace between the method name and the parameter list.

Comment: If my compiler was this pedantic, I would have stopped programming ***long, long ago***.

Comment: @hexafraction Compilers are basically this pedantic.

Comment: @clwhisk That's a convention, not a rule. I can stick whitespace in many places in different ways. I can write my 400-class game using one compilation unit where all of the classes are static nested classes, and are all on one line. The compiler won't die. As an extreme I can make a hello world program over 400 lines, mostly whitespace.

Comment: @clwhisk Try it and see what happens.

Comment: @clwhisk Can you clarify how it *should* be interpreted? I'm failing to see what you're trying to convey beyond how Alan interpreted it.

Comment: woah ok in future i'll build examples before making assumptions, my bad

Comment: @clwhisk it may be pedantic for a single character to kill, but a single whitespace won't kill in this contexr.

Comment: @clwhisk Why are you suddenly being defensive and implying that I am annoying? If you do not wish to carry on the conversation feel free to stop replying to comments and adding new ones at your leisure.

Comment: @clwhisk Are you referring to [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19368812/compiler-error-in-a-java-program#comment28702136_19368923)? If so I simply loaded from my inbox and jumped to yours right below, so with the grayness as well I missed it. In that case, my sincere apologies.